# How can I get the average of 5 grades of User?　Django

Tags: python, django

I am making a movie evaluation site using Djnago. This site allows each user to comment on a movie. At that time, I will give a 5-grade rating. How can I get the average of the 5-grade ratings of all users who commented on the movie?
Below is a model of the comment.

```
from datetime import datetime

from accounts.models import CustomUser
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator, MinValueValidator
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    stars       = models.FloatField(blank=False,null=False,default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                                                              MaxValueValidator(5.0)])
    user        = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    movie_id    = models.IntegerField()
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

view

```
def view_movie_detail(request, movie_id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.user  
        comment = request.POST.get("comment")
        stars = request.POST.get("stars")
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            user = User.objects.get(id=1)

        Comment(comment=comment, stars = stars, user=user,movie_id=movie_id).save()

        return redirect(f"/movie/{movie_id}/")
    else:
        data = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        recommendations = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        comments = reversed(Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id))
        average = 
        return render(request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", {
            "data": data.json(),
            "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
            "type": "movie",
            "comments": comments,
            "average" : average,
        })
```

Comment: Please share your `Movie` model.

Comment: The Movie model uses the TMDB API, so it only has movie_id.

Comment: If you know the movie_id, something like this could work : from django.db.models import Avg Comment.objects.filter(movie_id = 23).aggregate(AVG('stars'))

Comment: Where and how should I put this in?

Comment: @HermanTheGerman Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Original Answer:

Something like this should work, although I have not tested it:

```py
class Movie(models.Model):
    ...
    
    def get_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=self.id)
    
    def average_stars(self):
        comments = self.get_comments()
        n_comments = comments.count()
        
        return sum([comment.stars for comment in comments]) / n_comments
```

Then, you can access the average star rating of any movie by using:

```py
avg_star_rating = movie_obj.average_stars()
```

Also, consider changing the field `movie_id` of your `Comments` model to a `ForeignKey`. Something like this:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    stars       = models.FloatField(
                     blank=False,
                     null=False,
                     default=0, 
                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator(5.0)]
                  )

    user        = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    movie       = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Overall, your `models.py` should look something like this:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime


class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    
    def get_comments(self):
        return Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=self.id)
    
    def average_stars(self):
        comments = self.get_comments()
        n_comments = comments.count()
        
        return sum([comment.stars for comment in comments]) / n_comments
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' (' + str(self.average_stars()) + ')'


class Comment(models.Model):
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    stars       = models.FloatField(
                     blank=False,
                     null=False,
                     default=0, 
                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator(5.0)]
                  )

    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    movie       = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The `__str__` method override is just for testing purposes.

## EDIT:

Okay, so the above code works for getting the average of the scores for one movie. However, your code has issues in other places. I'll explain:

### 1

For your intended use case, the use of a `OneToOneField` for the user in the `Comment` model is incorrect. By using `OneToOneField`, you are limiting the number of comments that one user can make to one: a `User` can have at most *one* relation with a `Comment` object. What you *should* do instead is use `ForeignKey` for both the movie and the user and then make those two fields `unique_together`. That way, you cannot have more than one comment relating the same movie and user:

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'movie',)
    
    comment     = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    stars       = models.FloatField(
                     blank=False,
                     null=False,
                     default=0, 
                     validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0),
                     MaxValueValidator(5.0)]
                  )

    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie       = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at  = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    updated_at  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

### 2

Your `view` can be simplified a lot more. I assume you are building your form in your template from scratch - field by field. In django, there is a much better way of creating, serving and validating forms. It is done by extending `django.forms.ModelForm`.

To do this, you first need to create a file named `forms.py` inside your app folder. In it, you add this code:

```py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Comment

class CommentCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('comment', 'stars',)
```

And your `views.py` should be:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Comment, Movie
import requests
from .forms import CommentCreateForm

TMDB_API_KEY = 'somekey'

def view_movie_detail(request, movie_id):
    movie = Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Comment(
                comment = form.cleaned_data['comment'], 
                user = request.user,
                stars = form.cleaned_data['stars'],
                movie = movie
            ).save()
        return redirect('view_movie_detail', movie_id=movie_id)
    else:
        form = CommentCreateForm()
        data = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        recommendations = requests.get(f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{movie_id}/recommendations?api_key={TMDB_API_KEY}&language=en-US")
        comments = reversed(Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=movie_id))
        average = movie.average_stars()
        context = {
            "data": data.json(),
            "recommendations": recommendations.json(),
            "type": "movie",
            "comments": comments,
            "average" : average,
            "form": form,
        }
        return render(request, "Movie/movie_detail.html", context)
```

Here, I have also changed your `redirect` statement. It is better to refer to urls via their names, instead of their explicit pattern, as this will make it easier if you want to change the pattern later - you won't have to go back and modify your redirect. I have assumed your `urls.py` for this app is something like this:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('movie/<int:movie_id>/', views.view_movie_detail , name='view_movie_detail'),
]
```

Finally, in your template (`movie_detail.html`):

```html
...

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Post Comment</button>
</form>

...
```

This renders your whole form automatically, with no need to create the fields manually with `html` and `js`. You can take a look at `crispy_forms` if you want to easily style your form. Also, you can render the fields of the form individually if you want to change the layout:

```html
...

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Comment</p>
    {{ form.comment }}

    <p>Stars</p>
    {{ form.stars }}
    
    <button type="submit">Post Comment</button>
</form>

...
```

### 3

One last thing I would do is handle the cases where there are no comments yet differently:

```py
def average_stars(self):
   comments = self.get_comments()
   n_comments = comments.count()

   if n_comments:
      return sum([comment.stars for comment in comments]) / n_comments
   else:
      return 'No comments posted yet'
```

Comment: Does the Movie class just have a movie_id?

Comment: The `Movie` class has whatever attributes you want to give it, but there is no need to give it a `movie_id` attribute. It is already accessible from any other model that has a `ForeignKey` relation with `Movie`. That is why you can use `Comment.objects.filter(movie_id=self.id)` without needing to specify a `movie_id` attribute in the `Movie` class or in the `Comment` class (you just need a `ForeignKey` to `Movie` in the `Comment` model).

Comment: You cannot use get_comment () with this Movies model.
Error occurs.

Comment: You cannot use get_comment () with this Movies model.
Error occurs.
Commnents don't have movie_id. So , get_comments(self)can not be done.

Comment: Another error occurs.
NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment.movie_id

Comment: There was a small mistake with the `on_delete` parameter of the movie foreign key, but it is now fixed. I just tested it and it works for me.

Comment: When I do get_comments () in view, I get the error NOT NULL constraint failed: Movies_comment.movie_id.

Comment: Added the view function.
Calculate the average of the evaluation numbers in avarage.

Comment: Many users want to comment on each model of the movie one by one. Doesn't this make the comment have a lot of Movies?

Comment: movie = Movie.objects.get (id = movie_id) raises the error Movie matching query does not exist.

Comment: That is because there is no movie with the `id` that you are trying to query (`movie_id`). Try putting the `id` of a movie that you know definitely exists in the `url` parameter.

Comment: You can handle non-existent movies by doing that query using `.filter(id=movie_id).first()` instead of `.get(id=movie_id)`. Then, if the movie does not exist, the query will return `None` instead of an exception. You can then decide what to do in case `movie == None` (for example, render another template that tells the user that the movie does not exist).

Comment: Hello, @panda, did my answer solve your problem? If so, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please provide more details so I can help you!